# Volatile array of nodes

Tags: java, arrays, volatile

I've declared a volatile array of node based data structures.

```
volatile Node[] name;
```

For the most part, I don't need each individual node to be volatile because I update the entire array when it needs to be updated.

```
name = new array of nodes;
```

Rarely, I will need to update a field inside a specific node of the array, but no other thread will need to read this field for at least several minutes. Can I assume that at this point, whatever change I've made would be visible to other threads?

Comment: If I need access to the fields within the node/object to be volatile, is it sufficient to declare those fields as volatile or do I also need to declare the node/object as volatile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case you describe, the `volatile` keyword on `name` doesn't come into play at all.  Your use of `volatile` will only be relevant on reads from and writes to `name`, neither of which are done when accessing some field of some element in `name`.

If you need to read guarantees on some field in some element of `name`, you really need to make *that* field `volatile`.

Comment: with that field volatile, does it matter that the element containing the field is not volatile?

Comment: -1 This is not true. writes before the write to volatile are visible to reads that occur after a subsequent read of the volatile. As long he doesn't change the elements in the array outside these circumstances, there's no problem. However, he says he does, but the reads and writes are separated by several minutes. Such a program is definitely not correct, but whether in practice he'll have problems I don't know.

Comment: @Artefacto: I'm not sure which part you're saying isn't true.  I was saying that slapping a volatile on `name` doesn't synchronize memory access to fields of elements of `name`.  The happens before invariant you mention does occur, but I fail to see how its relevant at all here since the write and read of some field of an element of `name` don't appear related to the write to `name`.  They could both happen after.  Can you be a bit more specific with your reason for downvoting?

Comment: Oh I think I see where you're coming from.  When I said "`volatile` only makes guarantees on reads and writes to `name`" what I meant was its effect only comes into play when reading from or writing to `name`.  I didn't mean to imply that the memory synchronization that you describe doesn't occur, though if my memory serves that was added with 1.5, long after the volatile keyword was added to the language.

Comment: @Mark Reading an element of the array (through the array) implies reading the array. For instance, `CopyOnWriteArrayList` relies on this (check its implementation).

Comment: @Artefacto: Yes, it does, but that has no bearing on a field *within* an element of an array.  You could have an external reference to a `Node` that's also within the array

Comment: Suppose I had a dummy volatile that's set to false before a write to the field is made and set to true after the write has been made (so whatever changes I've made before the volatile write also get flushed to "main memory"). If my other threads are set only to read when my dummy volatile is true, do I get "volatile" behavior on the field in an element of an array?

Comment: @Mark It *does* have a bearing on fields of the elements of the array. What makes you think it doesn't? If that field was written to before the writing the volatile reference, its value is available after reading the volatile reference.

Comment: @Artefacto: I'm not saying it doesn't.  What I'm saying is that if the field is written to, and another thread reads it without an intermediate write+read to the volatile variable, then the happens-before invariant won't necessarily be true.  I mean it has no bearing in that it's no more special than any *other* reads you do.  The volatile variable holding the array has no more bearing on fields in elements within the array than it does on any other arbitrary field in the program.

Comment: @lgp: Yes, you do so long as you're using 1.5+.

Answer (score 0):

in this case volatile refers only to reference to array, not to its items
when (as you said) no other thread will need to read this field for at least several minutes there is very small risk, but still it exists

Comment: if whatever thread that updated the field died, will the changes that the thread made get flushed to "main memory"?